# sum if a date month AND year is greater than today

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

Trying a sum if date month and year is greater than today,

```
=SUMIF(A4:A51,">=month(TODAY())&YEAR(TODAY()))",Q4:Q51)
```

where column `A` is dates and Column `Q` numbers that I want to sum. Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what the values in  `A4:A51` look like?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample sheet with input and your desired output. Remove sensitive information please.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your formula:

1. The comparison operator ">=" and the date value need to be concatenated together as a string within the formula.
2. The month and year functions within the formula need to be nested within the date function.
3. The closing parenthesis for the SUMIF function is in the wrong position.

Try this

`=SUMIF(A4:A51,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),Q4:Q51)`

`">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)`
This formula concatenates the comparison operator ">=" with the current year and month using the DATE function. The DATE function creates a date value based on the year and month provided, with the day set to 1. This creates a date value for the first day of the current month and year.

Comment: what if i want to calculate from a month after from todays date. I means istead of today that is April start from May

Comment: Try changing `MONTH(TODAY())` in the answer above to `EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+1`

Comment: ```MONTH(TODAY())+1```, this adds 1 to the current month to get the next month's number.